# Generating columns for daily stats in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table that currently looks like this (simplified to illustate my issue):

```
Thing| Date
1     2022-12-12
2     2022-11-05
3     2022-11-18
4     2022-12-01
1     2022-11-02
2     2022-11-21
5     2022-12-03
5     2022-12-08
2     2022-11-18
1     2022-11-20
```

I would like to generate the following:

```
Thing| 2022-11 | 2022-12
1        2         1
2        3         0
3        1         0 
4        0         1
5        0         2
```

I'm new to SQL and can't quite figure this out - would I use some sort of FOR loop equivalent in my SELECT clause? I'm happy to figure out the exact syntax myself, I just need someone to point me in the right direction.

Thank you!

Comment: It sounds like you want a `GROUP BY` id. The issue with answering this though the the dynamic of the output columns. Does your output need to look exactly like this? If so, what specific database are you using?

Comment: Could you please tag your DBMS?

Answer (score 1):

You may use conditional aggregation as the following:

```
Select Thing, 
       Count(Case When Date Between '2022-11-01' And '2022-11-30' Then 1 End) As '2022-11',
       Count(Case When Date Between '2022-12-01' And '2022-12-31' Then 1 End) As '2022-12'
From table_name
Group By Thing
Order By Thing
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/3ukZUuSv).

The count function counts only the not null values, so for each row not matching the condition inside the count function a null value is returned, hence not counted.

Comment: Hard to believe such hard coded date conditions are wanted. I assume the data should generally be "grouped by" the month they appear.

Comment: Why not? The answer solves the OP problem, if there are any other issues the OP should clarify them so I may update the answer or somebody else post another answer.

Comment: I wrote why. If further data with other months appear, further counts with case when would be required. This could be extremely long and bad to read depending on how many months occur. To be fair: I'm not sure yet if/how there is a better approach, one reason of this is that the OP didn't tag their DBMS. Of course, your answer is a good point to start, my comment does not deny this.

Comment: Yes, I understand and agree with you, I posted this answer just as you said *point to start*

Comment: If the OP needs columns created dynamically based on the range of data then that's a very different solution which they need to make clear, with the solution depending on the specific platform.